# Assigning different classes using ArcGIS Field Calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser, arcgis-10.6

Below is the code with what I have come up with. I have two columns, one named `First_kopp` that have the classes `CT`, `WT`, `ST` ranging from 1-9, and the second column is named `First-fros`. There are conditions that have to be met based on both columns as expressed in the code below, however, this code does not seem to work:

```
def reclass(FIRST_KOPP , FIRST_FROS):
   if 'CT' in FIRST_KOPP: 
               return "High frost risk"
   elif 'ST1' or 'ST2' or 'ST3' in FIRST_KOPP:
               return "Frost free"
   elif 'ST1' or 'ST2' or 'ST3' in FIRST_KOPP and 'Moderate frost risk' or 'High frost risk' in FIRST_FROS:
               return "Low frost risk"
   elif 'ST4' or 'ST5' or 'ST6' or 'ST7' or 'ST8' or 'ST9' in FIRST_KOPP:
               return "Frost free"
   elif 'WT' in FIRST_KOPP and 'Frost free' in FIRST_FROS:
               return "Low frost risk"
   else:
               return FIRST_FROS
```

Comment: You can also use any: `elif any(x in FIRST_KOPP for x in ['ST1','ST2','ST3'])`

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to get the script to work. After every `or` it is important to state in which column. Such as `ST1 in Frost_Kopp` or `ST2 in Frost_kopp`, etc

Comment: your first two "elif" condition test both for "'ST1' or 'ST2' or 'ST3' in FIRST_KOPP" regardless of syntax issue if the firsts is true the second wont be evaluated....